# How to take sample of data from very unbalanced DataFrame so as to not lose too many '1'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sampling

I have a Pandas DataFrame like below with ID and Target variable (for machine learning model).

- My DataFrame is really large and unbalanced.
- I need to make sampling on my DataFrame because it is really large
- Balancing the DataFrame looks like this:

  - 99.60% - 0
  - 0.40 % - 1

    | ID | TARGET |
    | --- | --- |
    | 111 | 1 |
    | 222 | 1 |
    | 333 | 0 |
    | 444 | 1 |
    | ... | ... |

How to sample the data, so as not to lose too many ones (target = 1), which are very rare anyway? In the next step, of course, I will add the remaining variables and perform over sampling, nevertheless at the beginning i need to take sample of data.

How can I do that in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want a sample size = 1000

Try to use the following line :

```py
df.sample(frac=1000/len(df), replace=True, random_state=1)
```

Comment: Looks interesting, it is stratify sampling as I assume, yes ? So using your code I will receive sample with 1000 observations with the same proportion of 1/0 like in my original dataset, yes ?

Comment: You can aslo use : `df.sample(frac=1000/len(df), replace=True, random_state=np.random.RandomState())` , but I think there is an issue of duplicates here, but we can fix it

Comment: replace = False, and I will not have duplicates in ID, but Am I right that using your code I will receive sample with 1000 observations with the same proportion of 1/0 like in my original dataset, yes ?

Comment: Basically, in sample size of 1000 observations you will get 4 observations where TARGET = 1

Comment: On what basis did you calculate that 4 '1's will I get ?

Comment: I understood that in the your large DataFrame you have 0.4% of TARGET==1, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, ok now everything is clear for me, best answer gien :)

Comment: I don't understand why you accepted this answer. The sampling is clearly not stratified. You can get any number of 1s there. Including none. I visualized a proof for you here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UEa0XBYdRcfIb_jA6dXXJ9qLjxbWzAIS?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you need. `stratify` param makes sure you sample your data in a stratified fashion as you need

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(30000, 2)
y = np.random.randint(2, size =30000)
skf = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=100, test_size=100, stratify=y, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to combine Oversampling and Undersampling.

**Random Oversampling:** Randomly duplicate examples in the minority class.

**Random Undersampling:** Randomly delete examples in the majority class.

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

over = RandomOverSampler(sampling_strategy=0.1)
X, y = over.fit_resample(X, y)
under = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.5)
X, y = under.fit_resample(X, y)
```